# Ajax not working with a specific file name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Something really weird happened today and I cannot understand its behavior so if someone can help me to understand I would really appreciate it,

So I tried to do `ajax` call like below

```
var dto = {
    'entity': 'SOME_VAL'
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/WebService/checkout/applyCoupon.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dto,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error!');
    }
});
```

and it returned my website's HTML code instead of `JSON` return values. 
After a while I was able to resolve the issue by using the same code with diffrent file names.

```
url: '/WebService/checkout/applyCoupon.php', //NOT WORKING
url: '/WebService/checkout/applyCoupon2.php', //NOT WORKING
url: '/WebService/checkout/coupon.php', //NOT WORKING
url: '/WebService/checkout/apply.php', //WORKING
url: '/WebService/checkout/ap.php', //WORKING
```

It seems like it does not work when the file name contains `coupon` in it.
I have other websites running just fine using the exact same code with the file name `applyCoupon.php` so I do not understand why it won't work on a specific website. I can just simply use a different file name but I want to understand how/why it could happen. The environment is **IIS**.
 Can someone please help me to understand this issue? Thank you!

Comment: We don't have enough information to really diagnose, but I would assume that your IIS has some sort of [rewrite rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#using-server-variables-in-rewrite-rules), I would assume there was a previous mapping for some coupon page that may or may not exist anymore, but the rule is still there.  So it sees coupon in the URL and the request gets rewritten.  Or something along those lines.

Comment: @dave Yes there is url-rewrite rule but others website have the same rules with the same code and they are working fine. I think you are right. I am just curious why it would work on the others. Thank you so much for your comment, Dave!

Comment: Dave made a good point. He wanted to say that in a vhost config or  .htaccess(most likelly)  you have a rewrite rule.... I assume you are using a framework, so some of the module or pluging could potentially add this rule. Maybe this pluging or modul is not installed on other sites that explains the weird behaviour.

Comment: [remark] : **I have other websites running just fine using the exact same code** - For unix/linux , applyCoupon.php can be different from applycoupon.php/APPLYcoupon.php/ApPlYCoUpon.php, but it is not the case in IIS